# Выбор оптимального пути (python)

Tags: python, поиск-пути

Задача: У Кати насыщенный день на работе. Ей надо передать n разных договоров коллегам. Все встре- чи происходят на разных этажах, а между этажами можно перемещаться только по лестничным пролетам — считается, что это улучшает физическую форму сотрудников. Прохождение каждого пролета занимает ровно 1 минуту.
Сейчас Катя на парковочном этаже, планирует свой маршрут. Коллег можно посетить в любом порядке, но один из них покинет офис через t минут. С парковочного этажа лестницы нет — только лифт, на котором можно подняться на любой этаж.
В итоге план Кати следующий:
Подняться на лифте на произвольный этаж. Считается, что лифт поднимается на любой этаж за 0 минут.
Передать всем коллегам договоры, перемещаясь между этажами по лестнице. Считается, что договоры на этаже передаются мгновенно.
В первые t минут передать договор тому коллеге, который планирует уйти.
Пройти минимальное количество лестничных пролетов.
Помогите Кате выполнить все пункты ее плана.

Формат входных данных

В первой строке вводятся целые положительные числа n и t (2≤n,t≤100) — количество сотрудников и время, когда один из сотрудников покинет офис (в минутах). В следующей строке n чисел — номера этажей, на которых находятся сотрудники. Все числа различны и по абсолютной величине не превосходят 100. Номера этажей даны в порядке возрастания. В следующей строке записан номер сотрудника, который уйдет через t минут.

Формат выходных данных
Выведите одно число — минимально возможное число лестничных пролетов, которое понадобится пройти Кате.

```
n, t = input().split()
string = input().split()
l = list(map(int, string))
num = int(input())
count = []

final = l[num-1]
difference = max(l) - min(l)
super = final - min(l)

if super > int(t):
    count1 = max(l) - min(l) + max(l) - final
    count2 = max(l) - min(l) + final - min(l)
    count.append(count1)
    count.append(count2)
    print(min(count))
else:
    print(difference)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять что не так в коде. Многие тесты проходит, но на одном ступорит.

Comment: На каком именно тесте "ступорит" и что при этом вам сообщает  - это мы разумеется должны сами догадаться.

Comment: @passant тестовые данные недоступны, поэтому я и задаю вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Возможны следующие варианты:

`final-min<=t`  - идём с начала до конца, время `max-min`

`max-final<=t`  - идём с конца до начала, время `max-min`  - вот этого я у вас не вижу

если оба эти условия не выполняются, едем на `final`, потом на ближайший из концов, время `min(max-final, final-min) + max-min`

И до кучи - в коде **9 раз** производится поиск максимума и минимума в списке! Между тем при условии `Номера этажей даны в порядке возрастания` их искать вообще не нужно

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать это:

```
floors = list(map(int, input().split()))
leaving_colleague = int(input())

destination_floor = floors[leaving_colleague - 1]

# Первый вариант: передать документ коллеге, который уходит
if t < n:  # если время t меньше, чем общее количество коллег
    floors.remove(destination_floor)  # убираем этаж, на котором находится уходящий коллега
    floors.append(destination_floor)  # добавляем его в конец списка
    n -= 1  # уменьшаем общее количество коллег на 1, так как уходящий коллега уже не требует передачи документов
    count1 = max(floors) - min(floors)  # минимальное количество лестничных пролетов без учета уходящего коллеги
    count2 = max(floors[:-1]) - min(floors[:-1]) + max([destination_floor, floors[-1]]) - min([destination_floor, floors[-1]])
    # минимальное количество лестничных пролетов, если сначала передать документ уходящему коллеге, затем остальным
    print(min(count1, count2))
else:  # если t больше или равно n, то уходящий коллега не нужно учитывать
    print(max(floors) - min(floors))
```